# Disable price filter on category view Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm new to magento and keep learning :)

How can I disable the price filter to show on category view?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can disable price filter by setting up "use in layered navigation" to "NO" for price attribute.

Login to admin panel -> Store -> Attributes (under product section) -> search for price attribute code and go to edit mode -> go to storefront properties -> select "No" value for Use in Layered Navigation. -> click on save attribute.

then clear cache and check on category page.

Hope it would be right answer!

Comment: I want to hide this for some of my categories

Answer (score 1):

to  disable price filter set "use in layered navigation" to "NO" for price attribute in storefront properties.

go to backoffice -> Store -> Attributes -> search for price attribute click edit  -> click storefront properties -> select "No" value for Use in Layered Navigation. -> click on save attribute.

clear cache
[image]